# how to read first 5 lines of csv file using built in ruby csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, ruby-csv

My application lets user to upload csv file with maximum of 50MB. 
I wanted to show the user the preview of the uploaded file.
Can I read only the first 5 lines of csv? 
I am currently using CSV.read function, obviously this will read the entire file and is slow.

Comment: This should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236328/how-do-i-line-by-line-turn-a-csv-into-an-array-using-ruby

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`CSV#foreach`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-foreach) returns an enumerable, so just call [`Enumerable#take`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-take) on it:

```
csv_preview_data = CSV.foreach(csv_path, headers: false).take(5)
```

Comment: Does it reads only first 5 lines without loading all file in the memory?

Comment: @Зелёный `foreach.lazy.take(5).force` probably does is lazily.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest ways to read a fixed number of records for my opinion would be:

```
preview_data = CSV.readlines(csv_path, headers: false)[0,5]
```

Comment: This will load the entire CSV into memory, avoid this method for big files